# Why do SNMP walks fail here?

Tags: snmp, mib, oid, snmpwalk

I'm learning about zabbix and how to use SNMP to monitor networks. As a test, I wanted to create a MIB of my PC and find the CPU temperature.

So I got Paessler SNMP tester and started an SNMP walk. All was going well until OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.1.4.0 at which point it shows error:5. So, I tried it on a different PC with exactly the same point of failure. I can't find any info on what error 5 is. But since this happend on 2 PCs I'm wondering if its a common rookie mistake?? If doing a MIBwalk on a PC is a useless exercise?

I do see lots of interesting and useful items in the walk before it fails so hopefully there's a way to solve this.

Many thanks for your time and help in advance.

Searching the OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.77.1.1.4 on oidref.com shows its "comStatStart" and its an Object. And tried searching error5 for Paessler SNMP tester but no luck there. No info on what it is.

Comment: error 5 is a "genError" (general error), so it could be almost anything. You didn't mention the SNMP version, but I presume you are using SNMPv1, which only defines a handful of error codes. If possible, you should try the same thing using SNMPv2c, and you may get a more helpful error

Comment: Hi, thanks TallChuck. I was using SNMPv2c but tried v1 and got the same thing. I wonder if v3 might give a different result so I'll work out how and try that. I'm waiting for a response from Paessler (ive posted a question about error 5 on their knowledge base) so I'll add any more detail as I get it. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: No SNMP manager side tools/code/frameworks can answer why an error occurs. In almost all cases you need to contact the vendor of the SNMP agent you are testing against. Since you are testing with SNMP v2c, the network packets are not encrypted, so the vendor can easily tell what's up in just a few minutes if they know their products good enough.